# Por que obtengo el indice 0 siempre de un array float que se envía a un metodo de esta manera [F@3f4a9a9

Tags: java, android

estoy tratando de obtener el índice de un elemento de un array solo del elemento que tiene un mayor valor `[0.0012, 4.0120, 1.9922]` en este caso seria `1` pero este siempre me retonar la posición 0, este es el método que recibe el array float el cual e verificado y siempre le llegan valores con este `[F@c7ab500`

```
 private int argmax(float[] probs){
        Log.d("INDICE", "=> "+String.valueOf(probs)); //[F@c7ab500
        int maxIds = -1;
        float maxProb = 0.0f;
        for (int i=0; i<probs.length; i++){
            if(probs[i] > maxProb){
                maxProb = probs[i];
                maxIds = i;
            }
        }
        //retorna 0
        Log.d("INDICE", "=> "+String.valueOf(maxIds));
        return maxIds;
    }
```

La única manera de poder ver los valores del array float que le llega a este método que esta arriba es haciendo lo siguiente:

```
Arrays.toString(result[0])
```

Tengo un método que me retorna ese array con estos valores al imprimirlo con `Arrays.toString(result[0])`
los cuales son: `[0.9569464, 6.803377E-5, 0.042987211]`. Estoy usando `tensorflow-lite` este es el que retorna esa salida:

```
                tflite.run(imgData, result);
                txtPrediccion.setText("");
                txtPrediccion.setText("result= " + argmax(result[0])+" normal=> "+Arrays.toString(result[0]));
```

No se por que siempre el método `argmax(float[] probs)` me retorna `0` será por que le llega el array encriptado `[F@c7ab500`.

Gracias de antemano, cualquier ayuda será bienvenida.
Saludos.

Comment: `String.valueOf` no puede recibir un array de `floats`, es normal que te muestre información incorrecta. Para ver el array con todos sus elementos tienes que hacer `Arrays.toString(probs)`, pasándole todo el array y te retornará un `String` así: `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]`

Comment: Lo que te muestra por pantalla es normal porque estás haciendo un mal uso de `String.valueOf()`.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentarios, tal como dices "SuperG280" le modifique ahora si veo que le llega algo como esto `=> [0.9569464, 6.803377E-5, 0.042985633]``pero no se por que el método me retorna siempre la posición `0`. Si te fijas el valor mas alto esta en el indice `1` tenia que haber retornado retornado 1. No se OscarGarcia igualmente.

Comment: No, el mayor es el `0`. `6.803377E-5` si te fijas el exponente de la E es negativo. Tu código es correcto. Y para nombrar a la gente aquí en los comentarios, usa la @, para que nos lleguen notificaciones.

Comment: Exacto. El mayor elemento es `0.9569464 (0)`, que es mayor que `0.00006803377 (1)` y `0.042985633 (2)`.

Comment: No sabia del exponente negativos amigos, ahora veo que siempre mi modelo tensorflow-lite siempre me esta retornando en el indice 1 un valor con simbolo `E` el cual como dicen ustedes es negativo y siempre me retorna en la posición 0 y valor más alto `0.9569464`. Es un modelo con red neuronal convolucional, le estoy enviando una imagen. En python si clasifica bien. Les agradezco sus comentarios muy buenos. Excelente sigan así.

Comment: La `E` es equivalente a **diez elevado a**, por lo que `6.803377E-5` es `6.803377 · 10^-5`. Y `10^-5` es `0.00001`. También te recomiendo que uses como límite inferior `-Infinito` (`Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`). Así también podrás usar valores negativos como elementos de entrada. Aquí tienes la ejecución en línea: [https://repl.it/@ojgarciab/DefinitiveGentleEvaluations#Main.java](https://repl.it/@ojgarciab/DefinitiveGentleEvaluations#Main.java)

Comment: Excelente Oscar, Gracias por tu valioso aporte.